# iOS - UIWebview - play local video (downloaded from the internet)

Tags: javascript, ios, html, uiwebview, html5-video

I am trying to pre-cache my UIWebView html5 videos.

I am downloading the videos to `"file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/{ID}/Documents/VideoName.mp4"` and I am sending this link to Javascript and trying to update video's tag src:

```
vid.src = path;
vid.load();
```

When I am using a regular mp4 file url (from the web) it is working. But when I am using the local path above it does not work (when checking the `vid.currentSrc` property I see that it is not updated with the local video.

What am I doing wrong here? I know that if using videos that I pre-inserted to application root, I can play them with only video's name (did this in the past). Can I download a video to application root on run-time?
tnx!

**EDIT**

After some research it seems that the problem is with the html code being remote on the server not recognizing the local file on the phone.
One possible solution will be to save server response as a local html file (in the same directory of the video file), and change the video url to be only video's name:

```
src="video1.mp4"
```

It seems to work but it is kind of ugly/complicated solution

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a [MPMoviePlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) respectively [MPMoviePlayerViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller_class/Reference/Reference.html)?
It can play videos from an URL (-> your filepath), which means local file on your device or streamed over the internet.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. This will play the movie with the native player. I want to play the movie with the html5 video player, inside my html page (so this solution is not helping me).